# scoopとpycharmの組み合わせについて

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

scoopでインストールしたpythonがpycharmで使われてしまうようです。
これをpyenvでインストール設定したバージョンに変えたいのですが、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

scoop installでpython3.10.5だとして
pyenvでpython3.9.13をインストールかつglobal化
使いたいインタプリタは3.9.13
なのですが
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
どのように使用すれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: この辺のヘルプや記事が参考になるのでは？ [Python インタープリターを構成する](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html), [システムインタープリターを設定する](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html), [インタープリターのパスを管理する](https://pleiades.io/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html), [Windowsで環境を極力汚さずにPythonを動かす方法 (Scoop編)](https://qiita.com/rhene/items/a5616857981293d06940)

Comment: pyenv-win はまったく知らないのですが pyenv which python としたらglobalに設定されている3.9.13の実行コマンドの位置がでてきませんか?

Comment: まだ終えてないのですが、コマンドで出てきたファイルパスを指定しても
sdkが無効と出てしまいます・・・

Comment: こんなIssueがあって、その後の進展が無いようですが。[bug: PyCharm does not recognize pyenvs python correctly #302](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/issues/302) それからPyCharmは出てこないけれどpyenv関連の記事がこちら。[AI 開発環境構築(主に windows10) - pipenv, pyenv を使った仮想環境 -](https://hackmd.io/@wKMCwarHTXytatMxSjcWhQ/Sk5ejv-xU) そしてMacOS系の古い記事。[pycharm, pyenvを使って既存のpythonプロジェクトの環境構築](https://qiita.com/fujiwarawataru/items/eb7b32b861e53e3040dd), [PyCharmをインストールしてpyenvの設定を使えるようにする](https://nekodeki.com/tag/pyenv/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
おそらくこのまま読み進めて設定すればいいのかなと思いましたが、vscodeで実装するようになってしまったので、必要ないかもしれません。
改めてjetbrainが必要になった場合は質問するかもしれません。